# How to convert a firebase query result to string and set it in a text view?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm querying through Firebase to extract data and set it into a text view, but the results are different.

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tables");
    query = databaseReference.child("restaurantID").orderByChild("tableID").equalTo(tableID);
    tableDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tables");
    tableNameQuery = tableDatabaseReference.child("tableName").orderByChild("tableID").equalTo(tableID);
    tableNameTextView.setText(tableNameQuery.toString());
```

It is not showing any error but the textview is showing as `com.google.firebase.database.Query@c1d4fdd`

Please help.

Comment: You have to add listener like `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` on query and listen response inside `onDataChange` where you should set the result to `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually performing a query against the database.  All your code is doing is taking the Query object returned by `tableDatabaseReference.child(...).orderByChild(...).equalTo(...)` and converting that object into a String.  What you are seeing is the default representation of a Java object as a String.

You should follow the [doucmentation for querying Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) in order to get actual data.  You will need to attach a listener to the Query to get data from it.  For example, from the documentation:

> ````
>     @Override
>     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>         for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
>             // TODO: handle the post
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>         // Getting Post failed, log a message
>         Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
>         // ...
>     } }); ```
> ````

Comment: null pointer exception
`tableDatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tables");
  tableNameQuery= tableDatabaseReference.child("tableName").orderByChild("tableID").equalTo(tableID);
tableNameQuery.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String restaurantName = dataSnapshot.child("restaurantName").getValue().toString();
            tableNameTextView.setText(restaurantName);

        }
    };`

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post a separate question and explain what you're trying to do, including the code that doesn't work the way you expect, and what you've done to debug it.